# (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the RunInstances operation: The parameter groupName cannot be used with the parameter subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, docker-run

Following [the example in AWS-CLI documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-ec2-instances.html#launching-instances) I tried running an EC2 instance using AWS CLI but got the error

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the RunInstances operation: The parameter groupName cannot be used with the parameter subnet
```

Instead of pulling each piece of information manually I thought it'd be easier to set them as environment variables then pass them onto `docker run`

```
export AMI_ID=ami-0b2ca94b5b49e0132
export KEY_NAME=$(aws ec2 describe-key-pairs --query 'KeyPairs[*].KeyName | [0]' --output text)
export SG_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=group-name,Values="my-sg" --query 'SecurityGroups[*].GroupId | [0]' --output text)
export SUBNET_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-subnets --query 'Subnets[*].SubnetId | [0]' --output text)
export VPC_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-vpcs --query 'Vpcs[*].VpcId | [0]' --output text)
docker run --rm -it -e AMI_ID -e KEY_NAME -e SG_ID -e SUBNET_ID -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws -v $(pwd):/aws amazon/aws-cli ec2 run-instances --image-id ${AMI_ID} --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name ${KEY_NAME} --security-group-ids ${SG_ID} --subnet-id ${SUBNET_ID}
```

Other posts I've found so far suggest that the problem is with using the `--security-groups` arguments instead of the `--security-group-ids` but I'm already using the latter so I'm stuck.

Comment: Where exactly are you using `groupName` in run-instances?

Comment: I'm not. That's why it's confusing. I found an answer though. Posting now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what the problem with the previous syntax was but when declaring the environment variables they are tagged on with additional characters like `$'`in the beginning and `\C-M'` in the end.

```
export AMI_ID=ami-0b2ca94b5b49e0132
export KEY_NAME=`aws ec2 describe-key-pairs | jq -j '.KeyPairs[0].KeyName'`
export SG_ID=`aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=group-name,Values="my-sg"  | jq -j '.SecurityGroups[0].GroupId'`
export SUBNET_ID=`aws ec2 describe-subnets | jq -j '.Subnets[0].SubnetId'`
```

Also the previous `docker run` was bloated because the environment variables are replaced by shell before `docker run` is executed and since they are not used again within the image they don't need to be passed on. So the shorter command would be

```
docker run --rm -it -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws -v $(pwd):/aws amazon/aws-cli ec2 run-instances --image-id $AMI_ID --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name $KEY_NAME --security-group-ids $SG_ID --subnet-id $SUBNET_ID
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, below does not work and gives me "The parameter groupName cannot be used with the parameter subnet" error even group name was not used.

```
--security-group-ids "sg-12345 sg-67890 sg-abcde"
```

This works (remove the quotes)

```
--security-group-ids sg-12345 sg-67890 sg-abcde
```

AWS CLI's error messages are notoriously misleading!